# Failed to parse XML in Android Manifest after update

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest

I have an app I was working on a few months ago. Today I opened it again in Android Studio 3.4 and when syncing it asked if OK to upgrade to the current version of Gradle and the Gradle plug-in. I agreed and I now get an XML parsing error in the manifest.

The manifest is here, I added a comment to signal where I get the error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.schalkx.alarmapp01">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SetAlarmActivity">
        android:label="Alarm Settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" <!-- *** I GET THE ERROR HERE *** -->
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ShowClockActivity">
        android:label="Desktop Clock"</activity>

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />

    <activity
        android:name=".UserResponseActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_user_response" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

I did some tests adding a new activity and I noticed that the syntax is now generated a bit differently, and would start like this:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".SetAlarmActivity"
    android:label="Alarm Settings"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" 
....
```

That is, the ">" is not added at the end of

```
    <activity android:name=".SetAlarmActivity">
```

but later on. Trouble is I haven't been able to get the syntax right.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
<activity android:name=".SetAlarmActivity"
        android:label="Alarm Settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"> //<--Notice
```

Instead of

```
<activity android:name=".SetAlarmActivity"> //<--Notice
        android:label="Alarm Settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm :-)   I was placing the ">" after the meta-data tag.

Comment: Q: In my case, the manifest was generated and updated by Android Studio so I would suppose it would  take care of these syntax thingys. Any idea why this happenned?

Comment: @kxtronic Not sure. Did you touch it yourself?